# install postfix and store all incoming mails in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, email, postfix

i cant config. postfix correcly, could someone please help me with that?

the google results i find, aren't really helping me..

its about a problem i try to solve for weeks now..

so: i need to be able to receive emails that are sent to email adresses using my Domain name, for example(badabum@domainName.com), this email will contain informations as a string, which i need to store in my database.
getting the information is not a problem, ad i would just do that with php or node.js.
all i need help with, is receiving emails and storing the body of those mails in my database ad strings.
i couldn't really find helpful answers in the web, cause all those solutions are for full mail servers that send, receive and filter spam and viruses, what i obviously don't need!
also all these answers i found assume that you have high level skills in what you do*ubuntu and mailservers*, which i really dont have..

im currently working on an Project which will help me finance my Collage, which starts october this year, when collage starts, i wont have time to finish my project, so 8 months of hard work would be destroyed=/.. therefore i really need your help to finish this.

what i have so far: i have an ubuntu vSerber, it has mysql and so on, so all i need is the software to receive emails.
i also have bought a domain.

please tell me now what i need,
i have installed postfix, but how do i need to config. it? i cant get it started..=/
ad what else do i need to install to ensure that all received mails are directly stored in my database?

please just answer if you know anything:) it would help me a lot!

tnak you!

Comment: english forum, you are wrong :(

Comment: ill rewrite it, sry :D

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use node.js anyway, take a look at this simple smtp-server written in node.js: https://github.com/baudehlo/Haraka

Comment: looks really promising, i'll read me through! thank you:)

Answer (score -1):

configuration of postfix. solltest dich aber an die sprache hier halten.
http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html

Comment: ok danke, ich lese mich da mal durch! an die Sprache halten? du meinst englisch?

Comment: jap, hier ist nur english erlaubt:)

Comment: alles klar, beitrag übersetzt:)

Comment: ich werd nicht schlau aus dem ganzen =/
domain ist domain.de, der server= h123.server.net
als mx record muss ich also bei domain.de h123.server.net angeben, richtig?
oft wird im internet von sowas wie mail.h123.server.net geredet, aber was kann ich ja nicht machen?!  
irgendwas konfiguriere ich so falsch dass postfix nicht einmal startet=/
 und da half mir dein link leider auch nicht../